# how to get an element width on mouseover using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get width of elements on mouseover. Every element has its own width, if mouseover on an element, I should get an alert with its width. Any help?

Thanks-

Comment: Why would you want this? It would be constant popups!

If you just need it for debugging you should download firebug or developer tools

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the width of a DOM element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175699/get-the-width-of-a-dom-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#el").mouseover(){ 
    var width = $(this).width(); 
    alert(width)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this).width()`

So you may have

```
<input type=text class="myText">
```

then your jQuery

```
$(".myText").hover(function(){
    alert($(this).width());
});
```